# How do I fix large addition/deletion from libraries in git history?

Tags: git, github

When I started this project I did not include the bower folder in my gitignore, I later on added the folder to my gitignore. This has caused a spike of additions and a spike of deletions:

[image]

How can I go back in time and fix this to remove the addition and deletion of those assets to avoid the spikes in this chart and other similar charts/statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with rewriting **all of the history of your repo** since you added the assets, you can do this using `git rebase`.

First, identify the commit that added the unwanted assets. It seems like it's the first commit in your repo based on your description.

Then, run `git rebase -i --root` (you don't need the `--root` if the assets were added later than the very first commit). Find the commit that added the assets in the list, and change the command at the front of the line from `pick` to `edit`.

Execute the rebase. When it pauses to allow you to edit the commit, amend the commit to remove the assets, and allow the rebase to continue. That will be something like:

```
git rm assets/bower
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

You may encounter a merge conflict during the rebase when the rebase plan tries to apply the commit that removes all of the assets. If so, simply resolve the conflicts by removing the assets again with `git rm assets/bower` or whatever is appropriate for your repository.

Finally, once you're satisfied with the results, you'll need to force push to GitHub since you'll be changing **every single commit** since you added the assets.